# How do I solve $3n^2+3n-1=0\pmod{5}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How do I solve $3n^2+3n-1=0\pmod{5}$?

I know the answer should be $1  \pmod 5 $ and $3 \pmod5$, but am unsure how to get there. Thanks!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: As $5$ is quite a small number, you could check every possible congruence class modulo $5$.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by $2$ (mod $5$), so you get
$$n^2+n-2 = (n+2)(n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod 5.$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: @OP Beware: to properly finish you either need to check that the roots of the scaled polynomial remain roots of the original (or note that scaling by $2$ is *invertible*, by $\,1/2\equiv 6/2\equiv 3,\,$ so $f(n)\equiv 0\iff (2f)(n)\equiv 0).\,$  Generally, scaling by *noninvertible* factors can introduce extraneous roots. Being a problem in number (vs. field) theory, this is pertinent (viz. when working modulo *composite* integers).

Answer (score 1):

$3n^2+3n\equiv1\equiv6\pmod5$

$\iff5$ divides $3(n^2+n-2)=3(n+2)(n-1)$

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic formula still applies, as the integers modulo $5$ is a field (where division by $2$ is allowed), like the rational numbers and the real numbers (this is because $5$ is a prime number):

$$
n\equiv\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{3^2+4\cdot3}}{2\cdot3}\\
=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{21}}{6}
$$
Now, $-3$ is the same as $2$, $21$ is the same as $1$ and $6$ is the same as $1$. The square root (or rather *a* square root) of $1$ is $1$. So we simplify and get
$$
n\equiv\frac{2\pm1}{1}
$$
which is easily calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can complete the square in the usual way. For $an^2+bn+c=0$ it can work well to multiply by $4a$. Here, multiply by $12$ to give $$36n^2+36n-12=(6n+3)^2-21=(n+3)^2-1=(n+2)(n+4)=0$$

(you need to find a square root of $21$ modulo $5$).

Obviously with a base as low as $5$, it is easy to try all possibilities. The quadratic formula (which can be established by completing the square in this way) works provided the modulus is prime to $2a$ (because you have to divide by $2a$) and you get a solution if $b^2-4ac$ has a square root.

Comment: Note that this depends crucially on $4a$ being *invertible* - see my remark on Ted's answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Indeed. I think the condition I gave at the end implies this, though I wasn't explicit that this is necessary for the method I used. Working with prime modulus, as here, there are no non-trivial zero divisors.

Comment: Yes, I thought it worth further emphasis since there are frequently errors due to this (and it is tagged number theory, not field theory, so the OP may soon be working modulo composite integers).

Answer (score 1):

This quadratic equation has solutions, as in all fields, iff its discriminant has square roots. Now
$$\Delta= 3^2-4(-1)3\equiv 4-3=1\mod 5$$
is indeed the square of $1,-1$, so the solutions are given by
$$x_1, x_2\equiv (2\cdot 3)^{-1}(-3\pm1)\equiv -3\pm 1=-4,-2\equiv 1, 3\mod 5.$$